# How do I quit MATLAB after execution is finished through command?

Tags: matlab

Instead of writing `quit` in my `.m` file, can I do this through command? I want to close MATLAB right after the file execution is completed.

For example, this is my command

```
matlab -nodisplay < my_script
```

Thank you very much.

---

This is the actual command I was trying to make

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -r "try, basic_plot;end, quit"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "my_script; quit"
```

#### Edit:

Following Edric's recommendation, you'd better use one of these:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, my_script; end, quit"
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, my_script; catch, disp('failed'), end, quit"
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, my_script; catch e, your_error_handling_function(e), end, quit"
```

Comment: Best to ensure my_script has a try/catch block around the contents.

Comment: @Edric Is that a security measure with respect to the correctness of the program itself, or the quit? If it's the script itself, it would be handled by the user who's writing the code. This is a cloud app, so for us we only care about ending MATLAB because MATLAB is running indefinitely on our server. Thanks.

Comment: It ensure that you reach the quit.  If you throw an error in 'my_script', you will abort that program and never get to the quit.

Comment: @CppLearner as Marc points out, it's to ensure you get to the "quit". If you're going to execute arbitrary user code, you need to be incredibly defensive.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to put `quit` at the end of the script does not guarantee that MATLAB will exit, since there may be an error (including a syntax error), and the `quit` command will not be reached.

Since MATLAB R2019a, there is a [`-batch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2019a/matlab/matlab_env/commonly-used-startup-options.html) command line option, to run the script non-interactively, in contrast to using `-r`.

Answer (score -1):

write down in the last line of your .m file and when you run your simulation after it shows result it will quit itself.

```
[...] % code

quit
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, I did write quit in the script, but I wanted to avoid that. I want to do this in command line. Thanks. I think Simon's solution is what I wanted.

Comment: Please @Vicky do not use a signature in your posts (see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)). You may have noticed that people systematically removed it from your previous answers. So save your time and don't do it :)