# Save Matlab command line script errors to a log

Tags: matlab, shell, command-line, extract-error-message

I'm working with Matlab on a server cluster, therefore I have no display and use it via command line. Running scripts works fine with

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash my_script
```

To save the output to a log and quit Matlab after execution of `my_script`, I modified the command as follows:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "try, my_script; end, quit force" | tee simple.log
```

However, error messages that are displayed in the Matlab Desktop version are not displayed in the log, which makes debugging very difficult.

Is there a way to store matlabs output **with error messages** in a log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running on Linux, refer to these [command line arguments](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html). To get the output of matlab into a file you can call

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -logfile my.log -r "try; ...; catch e;.. "
```

From the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html)

> -logfile filename
>
> Copy Command Window output, including error reports, into filename, specified as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337067/how-do-i-quit-matlab-after-execution-is-finished-through-command) led me to a solution (on two lines for readibility):

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r 
    "try, my_script; catch e, disp(getReport(e)), end, quit force" | tee my_.log
```

Simple thing I was forgetting is that `try` swallows the error with the exception. `catch e, disp(getReport(e))` displays the error message as usual, even with line number. `tee simple.log`